# SwitchNavigator does starts with initialRouteName in React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to start the App with "LoadingScreen.js" but it keeps starting with "MainScreen.js"

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Platform, Image, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator, SwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import MainScreen from './screens/MainScreen'
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen'
import LoadingScreen from './screens/LoadingScreen'

const Total=createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    MainScreen,
    LoginScreen,
    LoadingScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'LoadingScreen'
  }
)

const AppSwitch=createAppContainer(Total)
export default AppSwitch;
```

Am I missing something? Thank you for your help

***Modified:

```
const Total = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Loading: {
      screen: LoadingScreen,
      path: "./screens/LoadingScreen"
    },
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      path: "./screens/LoginScreen"
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Loading'
  }
)

const AppSwitch = createAppContainer(Total)
export default AppSwitch;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try swapping screens as following

```
const Total=createSwitchNavigator(
  {
   LoadingScreen, 
   MainScreen,
   LoginScreen,
    
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'LoadingScreen' <<--- Ignore this property --->>
  }
)
```

More clearly defined here [Dynamic InitialRouteName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841723/how-to-set-dynamic-initialroutename-in-createswitchnavigator)

Comment: Thank you so much but it does not works. <***Modified> still starts with LoginScreen, not LoadingScreen. Any other suggestions?